# How to plot prediction intervals in seaborn tsplot?

Tags: python, time-series, plotting, seaborn

I am plotting a group of time series plots with CI's in seaborn using tsplot:

[image]

These were produced from 10 traces each:

[image]

The confidence bars shown (99% confidence) appear to be the CI's for the mean. However I am really after 99% confidence for the prediction interval. For the examples above these should be much wider and cross the red dotted line on occasion.

Can I plot 99% prediction intervals in seaborn tsplot?

Comment: Would you share your code and/or samples of the data in some way?